# How to get week of year for Jewish calendar

Tags: java, calendar, hebrew

I try to find the week of the year for Jewish to use it in a global app, which provides general services about the international calendar.

Comment: See this: http://www.david-greve.de/luach-code/jewish-java.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) which offers a Jewish/Hebrew calendar and use following code:

```
HebrewCalendar hebcal = HebrewCalendar.nowInSystemTime();
int weekOfYear = hebcal.getInt(HebrewCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

It uses the [default week model/definition](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/HebrewCalendar.html#getDefaultWeekmodel--) in Israel which starts the week on Sunday (after Sabbat).

**About interoperability with `java.time`:**

```
LocalDate gregorian = hebcal.transform(PlainDate.class).toTemporalAccessor();
HebrewCalendar jewish = PlainDate.from(gregorian).transform(HebrewCalendar.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the link [here](https://kosherjava.com/tag/jewish-calendar/) which provides example that might help you:

```
JewishCalendar israelCalendar = new JewishCalendar(5775, JewishDate.NISSAN, 7);
    israelCalendar.setInIsrael(true); //set the calendar to Israel
    JewishCalendar chutsLaaretzCalendar = new JewishCalendar(5775, JewishDate.NISSAN, 7);
    chutsLaaretzCalendar.setInIsrael(false); //not really needed since the API defaults to false
    HebrewDateFormatter hdf = new HebrewDateFormatter();
    System.out.println("Date\tChutz Laaretz / Eretz Yisrael"));

for(int i = 0; i < 57; i++){
        israelCalendar.forward(); //roll the date forward a day
        chutsLaaretzCalendar.forward(); //roll the date forward a day
        if(chutsLaaretzCalendar.getDayOfWeek() == 7){ //ignore weekdays
            System.out.println(hdf.formatParsha(chutsLaaretzCalendar) + "\t" + hdf.formatParsha(israelCalendar) + " \\ " + hdf.format(chutsLaaretzCalendar));
        }
    }
```